# Why is my Controller not populating Action Params?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm new to MVC and I have come across an issue.

Reading a blog by Stephen Walters (See [HERE](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/07/08/asp-net-mvc-tip-15-pass-browser-cookies-and-server-variables-as-action-parameters.aspx)), I see that MVC Action Params try to match against data in the HttpRequest object (Query String, Form, Cookie, and Server Variables). His example shows a standard action that gets 2 values:

```
public ActionResult Index(string HTTP_USER_AGENT, string myCookie)
{
    ViewData["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] = HTTP_USER_AGENT;
    ViewData["myCookie"] = myCookie;
    return View();
}
```

This should pick up HTTP_USER_AGENT and the value of a cookie (myCookie) if it exists.

However when I try to run this example, both params = null !

The cookie exists (I created it previously), if I try:

```
string c = Request.Cookies["myCookie"].Value;
```

It has the value I am expecting! More puzzling is HTTP_USER_AGENT being null

Any ideas???

Thanks!!!

Comment: Show the code where you call the `Index` method and the declaration of the parameters.

Comment: @JohnWillemse you don't call the `Index` method, the MVC framework does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC 3 and above contain default value providers for 4 collections:

`Form`, `RouteData`, `QueryString` and `File`.

There is no value provider for Cookie and Server Variables. But it seems that you can write your own value provider for these collections.

Example for Cookie:

```
public class CookieValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{
    public class CookieValueProvider : IValueProvider
    {
        private readonly HttpCookieCollection _cookies;

        public CookieValueProvider(HttpCookieCollection cookies)
        {
            _cookies = cookies;
        }

        public bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix)
        {
            return _cookies.AllKeys.Any(x => x.Contains(prefix));
        }

        public ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
        {
            if (_cookies == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var val = _cookies[key] == null ? null : _cookies[key].ToString();
            var val = _cookies[key];
            return val != null
                       ? new ValueProviderResult(val, val.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                       : null;
        }
    }

    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        return new CookieValueProvider(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies);
    }
}
```

and register it in global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
        ...

    ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new CookieValueProviderFactory());
    RegisterRoutes(...)
}
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks to all, yes I guess they must have removed it since MVC 3/4. Thought I was going mad! Thanks to all that answered pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

That blog article is from 2008 which is MVC1/MVC2 era.  Based on some of the comments on the bottom of the article regarding bad security implications of doing this, I think they removed this ability in MVC3 and MVC4.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the source code in `ValueProviderFactories.cs` and see these value providers listed:

```
public static class ValueProviderFactories
{
    private static readonly ValueProviderFactoryCollection _factories = new ValueProviderFactoryCollection()
    {
        new ChildActionValueProviderFactory(),
        new FormValueProviderFactory(),
        new JsonValueProviderFactory(),
        new RouteDataValueProviderFactory(),
        new QueryStringValueProviderFactory(),
        new HttpFileCollectionValueProviderFactory(),
    };

    public static ValueProviderFactoryCollection Factories
    {
        get { return _factories; }
    }
}
```

It looks like there is no cookies value provider or server variables provider.